# Erro em resposta de cURL de API da Envato, malformed token

Tags: api, libcurl

Estou tentando obter dados de templates do Themeforest usando [a API da Envato](https://build.envato.com/api#market_ItemPrices); preciso de dados como nome do template e preço a partir do ID do produto. Mas a resposta via cURL é que há um erro na formação. Não consigo identificar o problema, minha experiência com cURL, JSON e APIs é limitada.

O que estou usando:

```
$url = 'https://api.envato.com/v1/market/item-prices:'. $theme_id .'.json';
$personal_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

if (extension_loaded('curl') === true) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$personal_token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $err_status = curl_error($ch);
    
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {                
        $err = 'Erro: ' . curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $data;
    }
    else {
        curl_close($ch); 
        echo 'Completo sem erros: ';
        print_r($data);
    }       
}
```

A resposta exata é:

> "error": "Missing or malformed API token: You need to provide an API
> token to access the API. The token must be a 32 character long
> alphanumeric string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, encontrei a resposta: CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER em vez de CURLOPT_HEADER.

O código final e funcionando:

```
if (extension_loaded('curl') === true) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // remover em produção
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); // remover em produção
    
    $data = curl_exec($ch);     
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        curl_close($ch);
        $err = 'Curl erro: ' . curl_error($ch);         
        echo $data;
    }
    else {
        curl_close($ch); 
        $json = json_decode($data, true);
        echo 'Title: '. $json['name'] .'<br>';
        echo 'Price: '. $json['id'] .'<br>';
        print("<pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre>"); // DEBUG
    }   
}
```